# How to remove unwanted stuff from ImageField - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I want to remove currently and clear field from my django form.

forms.py

```
class MyUserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['user_phone','user_dob','user_gender', 'user_image', ]
```

I am using crispy_forms also

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality is provided by [ClearableFileInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.ClearableFileInput). If you don't want it, use FileInput instead:

```
class MyUserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['user_phone','user_dob','user_gender', 'user_image', ]
        widgets = {'user_image': forms.FileInput}
```